# Next.js, Supabase authentication - Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialSession')

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, supabase

I'm trying to implement to authenticate refering to [this page](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs).
But I got this error. I don't know how to solve or debug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdURv.png)

```js
// _app.tsx
import { createBrowserSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { SessionContextProvider, Session } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{
  initialSession: Session
}>) {
  // Create a new supabase browser client on every first render.
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())
  console.log(supabaseClient)
  
  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionContextProvider>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  return {}
}

export default MyApp;
```

And this is my dir structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H1Pu.png)

when I saw `pageProps`'s inside using `console.log` there is no `initialSession`.
But I don't know and wanna know the location of injection data (`initialSession`)

Comment: Please include the error message in your post, not as a screenshot!

Comment: This is probably due to your `getInitialProps` being empty. If you remove that completely you shouldn't have this error. Also any child page of this `_app.tsx` will have to return `initialSession` from its `getServerSideProps` method.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Okay thanks for advise! This was my first time so I just thought sceenshot is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

this problem may be caused by middleware if you are using middleware.ts do not send response in parameter and take a look at sample next js supabase projects

Here is my example;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3IW.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout if your provider is properly passed to the top of your children.

I just encountered the same issue now, and I felt so stupid after I realized that is passed my auth provider above my supabase provider rather than inside the supabase provider. I dont know if this answer relates to what you were facing.
but I hope it helps